# Waving Goodbye to everyone

Tags: discussion

I am super sorry, but I am going to leave this website. Before I go, let me talk about my favorite things on this website

1. You: You have gotten my whole life better from finding me on this website; so I really have to thank you
2. Moderators: Without them, this whole entire website would be erupted in chaos, stupid questons and more
3. Editors: Thank You for pointing out my mistakes and fixing them to make my post better, otherwise I would probably still have 10 reputation
         I am sorry, but I now have to go. THANKS EVERYBODY, I will miss you...

Answer (score 0):

Best of luck with your future endeavours.